# Flask Admin String Field with optional choice

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, wtforms, flask-admin

I use Flask Admin and i have class like this:

```
TITLE_LIST = ['name1', 'name2']


Page(Document):
     title = StringField(max_length=200, required=True, choices = TITLE_LIST)
     date_modified = DateTimeField()
```

I would like to provide choices to pick from and the user should also be able to type a title if he likes a different one. In my example, user can only choose one of titles provided in the list. Any ideas?

If that is not possible, I could maybe just suggest list entries using ajax?

Thanks.